# How to use GRUB in a virtual machine

Tags: 20.04, grub2, virtualization

I'm creating an assembly in cubic.  I configured grub so that the live version runs by default (without installation).  When booting from a real computer, everything works as it should; when starting from a virtual machine, the installation dialog still appears, which already asks “Try or install ubuntu”.  I'm editing Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.5

Comment: eject install media in cd drive settings